# Is there a way to import into verdaccio a npm packages with all its dependencies?

Tags: npm

I have recently discovered [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) and I think it can be a great solution to store packages on a private server. However I tried a few things to import from NPM some packages with their dependencies into Verdaccio but I did not manage to do anything successful...

Is there a way to import an NPM package and all its dependencies into Verdaccio (a script, a procedure to make a kind of 'bulk' download from the official NPM registry...) ?

Thank you in advance,

Pierre

Comment: Hi, here core maintainer. Bulk procedures like that no as I far I know.

Comment: Thank your for your response ! :) Is there at least a way to import a single package from the NPM registry to a Verdaccio server ?

Comment: Verdaccio is a proxy, so, if you install any package in your a local project, the tarball and the whole metadata get cached in verdaccio, so, in a way, it is the same that publish your self. So, if you create a script to install all your published versions for X package, you end up with a whole copy of all your tarballs in the verdaccio cache. It just a crazy idea :)

Comment: OK, I am starting to understand how your software work... I installed it using Docker with the default options. I have a question : if I transfer a package from the /verdaccio/storage directory from a Verdaccio instance to another instance, will this package be recognized ? (I think of that to push packages to an offline Verdaccio instance...)

Comment: Yes, it is. Verdaccio does not modify the metadata or tarballs in any way. Only private packages are "tagged" to be displayed in the UI. So, copy the full storage to other instances is a usual and valid procedure in users.

Comment: Thank your so much for your help and for Verdaccio. You will save me a lot a time ! I will try this next week...